# Exiting only Pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

Im running a Pygame window using a GUI. When for example, a user clicks on a button on the GUI, the Pygame window appears. However, when I want to quit the Pygame window, my GUI quits too. Im sure this is beacuse of the following lines of code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

sys.exit() exits everything, which is why the IDE closes with the Pygame window. But how do I only close the Pygae Window? Ive tried this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                break
```

But this doesnt work. Any suggestions?

The GUI im using Pyqt4 with Python 3.

Comment: What "doesnt work"? Suggestions for what?

Comment: My alternative code to only close the Pygame Window and not the pygame window and the GUI window

Comment: Sure: but what _actually happens_ in the second case? Does the pygame window close, neither window close, both windows close, or what exactly?

Comment: It close, but after endeless attempts of clicking the X button. It doesnt close as smoothly as using sys.exit, which closes everything.

Comment: Show the code where you exit the application's event loop

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your code snippet

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        break
```

is part of your main loop, running in an `while` loop, like

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
```

The problem is that `break` will exit the `for` loop, not the `while` loop, eventually leading to an exception since you exit pygame but are probably trying to draw an the screen etc. etc.

A simple fix is to use a variable as condition for your `while` loop, like

```
quit = False
while not quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            quit = True
        ...
```

or make sure to exit the `while` loop

```
while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): # only check for QUIT event
        break
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...
```